# Constant or Uniform Velocity and acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity

I get confused understanding  Constant or uniform Velocity and acceleration when I understand constant speed which means that same distance traveled at same time.

So constant or uniform velocity means same distance and same time which so no change in velocity or no change in speed. Hence if a say 4 m/s constant or uniform velocity it means the object is moving 4 m per second. So there is no increase or decrease of velocity / speed - is this true for what we mean uniform velocity?

Then again constant or uniform acceleration is same like constant or uniform velocity?

Hence Constant or uniform Velocity and acceleration would mean same as Constant or uniform speed then? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between speed and velocity? An object can have constant speed even though its velocity is changing.

Comment: Yes I know speed + direction = velocity but in terms of values say acceleration is constant or uniform 2 m/s2 would mean per second I am increasing acceleration by 2 (2,4,6,8,..) or that per second object is always accelerating 2 m. is it the same for uniform?

Comment: That's a bit confusing. If a body has constant (non-zero) acceleration then, by definition, the acceleration of the body isn't changing, but its velocity is changing.

Comment: Thanks so velocity is changing equal at equal interval of times - say 2,4.6.8 per second so acceleration is always 2 - is constant acceleration and uniform acceleration is same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition regarding constant/uniform speed is correct. If the velocity of particle is uniform (say $4$ $m/s$), that means its displacement from starting point increases by $4$ $m$ every second.

Now, in case of uniform/constant acceleration (say $4$ $m/s^2$), the velocity of the particle increases by $4$ $m/s$ every second.

It will be more clear by these graphs. 
[image]

Comment: Can't beat a picture!

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration is the change of velocity. Constant acceleration thus means that the speed is constantly changing. And by a uniform amount. Example: Every second you gain 9.8m/s in speed while falling.

Comment: Thanks so velocity is changing equal at equal interval of times - say 2,4.6.8 per second so acceleration is always 2 - is constant acceleration and uniform acceleration is same?

Comment: You got it. I guess 'uniform' is just used to avoid the oxymoron "constant acceleration"