# Are uniform acceleration and uniform motion the same?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology, velocity

Any answers are appreciated, thanks. :D

Comment: Please accept an answer if that answers your question.

Comment: I've answered a same question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/552617/constant-or-uniform-velocity-and-acceleration/552625#552625).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No!

Uniform motion is motion in which velocity is constant and acceleration is 0.

Uniform acceleration : Motion in which acceleration is constant , therefore velocity is increasing or decreasing or even just the direction is changing for example a uniform circular motion

**Note:** Every uniform motion is having uniform acceleration but vice-versa does not always hold true

Comment: Thanks! so uniform motion = velocity constant, a=0

Comment: and uniform acceleration = a constant, right?

Comment: @QAQ_123 Yes , that's right.

Answer (score 1):

No, uniform motion implies constant speed, whereas uniform acceleration means constant acceleration.